# "Internal Salesforce.com Error " (FATAL ERROR) During a Batch class run on creation of opportunity products

Tags: apex, trigger, batch, contentdocumentlink

We have created a Trigger on Content Document link Object which has a handler class which in turn calls a batch class.

The process is when a user upload a csv file it will create opportunity product.

We have a Template which will have all mandatory fields to avoid exeption etc..

However when we upload the file we get "Internal Salesforce.com Error" which we could not find the RCA.

Please find the associated class and trigger:

Trigger:

```
trigger contentDocumentLinkTrigger on ContentDocumentLink(after insert) {

if(Trigger.isInsert && Trigger.isAfter) {
    contentDocumentLinkTriggerHandler.afterInsert(Trigger.new);
}
```

}

Handler Class:

```
public class contentDocumentLinkTriggerHandler {

public static void afterInsert(List<ContentDocumentLink> newCDL) {
    
    if(newCDL != null) {
        Integer batchSize = Integer.valueOf(Label.Opportunity_Line_Item_Batch_Size);
        for(ContentDocumentLink cdl : newCDL) {
            String linkedId = cdl.LinkedEntityId;
            if(linkedId.startsWith('006')) {
                Database.executeBatch(new CreateOppLineItems_Batch(cdl.ContentDocumentId, linkedId), batchSize);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Batch Class:

```
public class CreateOppLineItems_Batch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful {

List<Database.SaveResult> saveResults = new List<Database.SaveResult>();
String documentId, opportunityId, fileName;
List<String> lines = new List<String>();

public CreateOppLineItems_Batch(String docId, String oppId){
    documentId = docId;
    opportunityId = oppId;
}

public List<OpportunityLineItem> start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    
    List<OpportunityLineItem> oppLineItems = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();
    
    if(String.isNotBlank(documentId) && String.isNotBlank(opportunityId)) {
        
        Map<String, List<OpportunityLineItem>> prodCodeAndOLIs = new Map<String, List<OpportunityLineItem>>();
        Map<String, String> fieldAPINameAndTypeMap = new Map<String, String>();
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> objectFields = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('OpportunityLineItem').getDescribe().fields.getMap();
        for(String s : objectFields.keySet()) {
            Schema.DescribeFieldResult lfieldLabel = objectFields.get(s).getDescribe();
            Schema.DisplayType dType = lfieldLabel.getType();
            fieldAPINameAndTypeMap.put(String.ValueOf(s), String.ValueOf(dType));
        }
        
        List<ContentVersion> contVersions = [SELECT Id,VersionData,ContentDocumentId,ContentDocument.Title FROM ContentVersion WHERE ContentDocumentId = :documentId AND FileType = 'CSV'];
        if(contVersions.size() > 0) {
            ContentVersion cv = contVersions[0];
            fileName = cv.ContentDocument.Title + '.csv';
            Blob blobBody = cv.VersionData;
            String body = blobBody.toString();
            try {
                if(String.isNotBlank(body)) {
                    lines = body.split('\n');  
                    if(lines.size() > 0) {
                        
                        List<String> header = new List<String>();
                        for(String str : lines) {
                            if(String.isNotBlank(str)) {
                                
                                List<String> datas = str.split(',');
                                if(header.size() == 0) {
                                    header.addAll(datas);
                                } else {
                                    
                                    OpportunityLineItem oli = new OpportunityLineItem();
                                    oli.OpportunityId = opportunityId;
                                    String prodCode = '';
                                    for(Integer i=0; i<header.size(); i++) {
                                        
                                        String head = header[i];
                                        String data = datas[i];
                                        if(String.isNotBlank(head)) {
                                            
                                            head = head.trim();
                                            if(head == 'ProductCode') {
                                                prodCode = data;
                                            } else {
                                                String dataType = fieldAPINameAndTypeMap.get(head.toLowerCase());
                                                if(dataType == 'PERCENT' || dataType == 'CURRENCY') {
                                                    if(String.isNotBlank(data)) {
                                                        data = data.trim();
                                                        oli.put(head, Decimal.valueOf(data));
                                                    }
                                                } else if(dataType == 'DOUBLE') {
                                                    if(String.isNotBlank(data)) {
                                                        data = data.trim();
                                                        oli.put(head, Double.valueOf(data));
                                                    }
                                                } else if(dataType == 'DATE') {
                                                    if(String.isNotBlank(data)) {
                                                        data = data.trim();
                                                        String sperator = data.contains('-') ? '-' : '/';
                                                        List<String> strList = data.split(sperator);
                                                        Date dt = Date.newInstance(Integer.valueOf(strList[2]), Integer.valueOf(strList[1]), Integer.valueOf(strList[0]));
                                                        oli.put(head, dt);
                                                    }
                                                } else if(dataType == 'STRING') {
                                                    if(String.isNotBlank(data)) {
                                                        data = data.trim();
                                                        oli.put(head, String.valueOf(data));
                                                    }
                                                } 
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    System.debug(':::oli:::' + oli);
                                    if(prodCodeAndOLIs.get(prodCode) == null) 
                                        prodCodeAndOLIs.put(prodCode, new List<OpportunityLineItem>());
                                    prodCodeAndOLIs.get(prodCode).add(oli);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if(prodCodeAndOLIs.size() > 0) {
                            
                            for(Product2 prod : [SELECT Id,Name,ProductCode,(SELECT Id,UnitPrice FROM PricebookEntries WHERE Pricebook2.IsStandard = true) FROM Product2 WHERE ProductCode IN :prodCodeAndOLIs.keySet()]) {
                                for(OpportunityLineItem oli : prodCodeAndOLIs.get(prod.ProductCode)) {
                                    oli.UnitPrice = prod.PricebookEntries.size() > 0 ? prod.PricebookEntries[0].UnitPrice : 0;
                                    oli.Product2Id = prod.Id;
                                    oppLineItems.add(oli);
                                }
                            } 
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch(Exception exp) {
                sendAnEmail('File Upload Failed', 'File upload got failed due to ' + exp.getMessage(), body, cv.ContentDocument.Title+'.csv');
            }  
            ContentDocument cd = new ContentDocument(Id=cv.ContentDocumentId);
            delete cd;
        }
    }
    return oppLineItems;
}

public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<OpportunityLineItem> scope) {     
    if(scope != null && scope.size() > 0) {
        List<Database.SaveResult> insertResults = Database.insert(scope, false);
        saveResults.addAll(insertResults);
    }
}

public void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) { 
    
    if(saveResults.size() > 0) {
        String csvStr = lines[0].trim() + ',Status,Message\n';
        Boolean successFlag = false, failureFlag = false;
        
        for(Integer i=0; i<saveResults.size(); i++) {
            System.debug(':::' + i + ':::' + saveResults.size() + ':::' + lines.size() +  ':::' + (saveResults.size() > i+1) + '\n:::' + lines[i+1] + '\n:::' + saveResults.get(i));
            Boolean isSuccess = saveResults.get(i).isSuccess();
            String dt = saveResults.size() >= i+1 ? lines[i+1].trim() : '';
            if(isSuccess) {
                dt += ',Success,Inserted';
                if(!successFlag) {
                    successFlag = true;
                }
            } else {
                Database.Error error = saveResults.get(i).getErrors().get(0);
                dt += ',Failed,' + error.getMessage();
                if(!failureFlag) {
                    failureFlag = true;
                }
            }
            csvStr += dt + '\n';
        }
        String sub, b;
            
        if(successFlag && failureFlag) {
             sub = 'File upload partially successfull'; b = 'File uploaded partially successfull. For more info please find the attached file.';
        } else if(failureFlag) {
             sub = 'File Upload Failed'; b = 'File uploaded failed. For more info please find the attached file.';
        } else if(successFlag) {
            sub = 'File Upload Success'; b = 'File uploaded successfully. For more info please find the attached file.';
        } 
        sendAnEmail(sub, b, csvStr, fileName);            
    }
}

public static void sendAnEmail(String subject, String body, String csvStr, String fileName) {
    
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    
    mail.setToAddresses(new List<String> { UserInfo.getUserEmail() });
    mail.setSenderDisplayName('File Upload Status');
    mail.setSubject(subject);
    mail.setHtmlBody(body);
    
    if(String.isNotBlank(csvStr)) {
        Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attachment = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
        attachment.setFileName(String.isNotBlank(fileName) ? fileName : 'Upload.csv');
        attachment.setBody(Blob.valueOf(csvStr));
        mail.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] { attachment } );
    }
    Messaging.sendEmail(new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> { mail });
}
```

}

Please Advise.

Comment: Please comment the ContentDocument deletion code present in the batch class's start method and check it. Let me know if it works.

Comment: @HemantKeni I did the same and still Im getting the same internal Salesforce.com Error